# sympy: rootfinding of parameterized function in range

Tags: constraints, sympy, polynomials, parameterized

I'm having trouble to find the root of a parameterized quintic polynome. Background is: I want to find the parameter `s_f` such that for any given parameter `d_f`, the curvature of the polynomial is smaller than a threshold (yeah .. sounds complex, but the math is rather straight);

```py
# define quintic polynomial (jerk-minimized trajectory)
# see http://courses.shadmehrlab.org/Shortcourse/minimumjerk.pdf
s = symbols('s', real=True, positive=True)
s_f = symbols('s_f', real=True, positive=True, nonzero=True)
d_0 = 0
d_f = symbols('d_f', real=True, positive=True, nonzero=True)
d_of_s = d_0 + (d_f - d_0) * ( 10*(s/s_f)**3 - 15*(s/s_f)**4 + 6*(s/s_f)**5 )
display(d_of_s)


# define curvature of d_of_s
# see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#In_terms_of_a_general_parametrization
y = d_of_s
dy = diff(d_of_s, s)
ddy = diff(dy, s)
x = s 
dx = diff(x, s) # evaluates to 1
ddx = diff(dx, s) # evaluates to 0

k = (dx*ddy - dy*ddx) / ((dx*dx + dy*dy)**Rational(3,2))


# the goal is to find s_f for any given d_f, such that k(s) < some_threshold
# strategy: find the roots of the derivative of k in the range of s∈[0, s_f]
dk = diff(k, s)
dk = simplify(dk)
display(dk)


# now solve
res = solveset(dk, s, Interval(0, s_f).intersection(S.Reals))
display(res)
```

The function `dk(s, d_f, s_f)` has two root in the interval s∈[0, s_f], however `solveset` returns this:

```py
ConditionSet(s, Eq(5400*d_f**2*s**4*(-s**2 + 2*s*s_f - s_f**2)*(2*s**2 - 3*s*s_f + s_f**2)**2 + (900*d_f**2*s**4*(s**2 - 2*s*s_f + s_f**2)**2 + s_f**10)*(6*s**2 - 6*s*s_f + s_f**2), 0), Interval(0, s_f))
```

.. which is afaik equivalent to: I can't solve this, we got infinite number of results. Well, this is true for the function in general. `limit(dk, s, -oo)` and `limit(dk, s, +oo)` is zero. But since I stated the domain interval, why am I not getting the two roots I'm expecting? I'd also expect to get a more granular result:

- set containing the roots for s < 0;
- set containing the roots for s > s_f
- the two roots when s∈[0, s_f]

I started with *solve()* and a lot of different assumptions on my symbols. I get different results for different assumptions, but no combination seems to yield what I need. When I state no assumptions, I get back a set with a huge condition and 8 roots, that don't seem real or correct. In general, the constraints are:

```
- all symbols are real
- s_f > 0
- d_f > 0
- s ∈ [0, s_f] (domain range .. the polynomial is only evaluated in this interval)
```

---

I guess the problem is that I'm not setting up my solveset correctly:

- how to specify that s_f and d_f are real? afaik the symbol
  assumptions are ignored when using solveset?
- how to specify intervals
  and assumptions on other multivariate functions, i.e. other symbols
  than the domain one?

---

This is what d_of_s look like for s_f = 1, d_f = 1

[image: d_of_s]

And this is what dk(s) looks like (I plotted outside the domain range to visualize the problem).

[image: dk(s)]

Comment: Are you familiar with the Abel-Ruffini theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem

Comment: I was not, interesting, thanks for the pointer.If I got this right, there is no general solution to the general problem of root-finding of a 5th order polynomial, but for each special case of this type, there is at least one special (complex) solution? What does it tell me about my specific problem?

Comment: The Abel Ruffini theorem says that there is no general formula for a quintic or for polynomials of higher order (actually the important factor of `dk` is of order 10 in `s`). Specific numeric examples (without symbols) can have an analytic solution in terms of radicals. Some cases with symbols like `a*s**5 + b*s**3 + c*s` can be factored. Otherwise only numeric solutions are possible and for those you can not have unknown symbols like `s_f` in the equation.

Comment: But the roots of `ddy` can be determined easily with the two unknowns. Where's the difference?

Comment: That's because ddy has the exact form that I showed. There is no constant term so a factor of s can be pulled out leaving a quartic to be solved.

Comment: alright, I give up then. So this is not solvable and not an issue of sympy or sympy's solvers, but just not possible (right now). I'll have to find another way then. Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 1):

Substitute in the known values of `d_f` and `s_f` and use `real_roots` to find the real roots of the numerator of `dk`. Keep the ones that have a value in the range of interest:

```
>>> s_fi = 3
>>> [i for i in real_roots(dk.subs(d_f,2).subs(s_f, s_fi).as_numer_denom()[0])
... if 0 <= i.n(2) <= s_fi]
[CRootOf(800*s**10 - 12000*s**9 + 74000*s**8 - 240000*s**7 + 432000*s**6 - 410400*s**5 
+ 162000*s**4 - 4374*s**2 + 13122*s - 6561, 1), CRootOf(800*s**10 - 12000*s**9 + 
74000*s**8 - 240000*s**7 + 432000*s**6 - 410400*s**5 + 162000*s**4 - 4374*s**2 + 
13122*s - 6561, 2)]
```

I kept the CRootOf instances because they can be computed to arbitrary precision, e.g. to 3 digits:

```
>>> [i.n(3) for i in _]
[0.433, 2.57]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What's the intuition for the substitution?

Comment: You used `s_f = d_f = 1 in the picture`; I picked something of similar magnitude for demonstration purposes.

Comment: The substitution is necessary to find numeric solutions and as I explain in my comment above analytic solutions are not possible in this case